# Directus delete Item by ID

Tags: directus

How can you delete a item via Api in Directus?

According to the [doku](https://docs.directus.io/reference/items.html#delete-an-item) the path would be:

> DELETE /items/:collection/:id

I tried this but only got an error:

> DELETE /items/parking_reservations/61

```
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "\"value\" must contain at least one of [query, keys]",
        "extensions": {
            "code": "FAILED_VALIDATION"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete an item via the API in Directus using the DELETE method. You can perform this action by sending a request with the item's id to the items endpoint. For example, if you wanted to delete an item with the id of 42, you would send a DELETE request to the following endpoint: `/api/1.1/tables/<table_name>/rows/42`.

Comment: When I try this it returns a HTTP Statuscode 405 Method not allowed